# Prevent incorrect expansion of \! in index

Tags: indexing, makeindex, texlive-2020

I recently upgraded from texlive-2019 to texlive-2020, and my index command broke.

The relevant code is:

```
\newcommand{\BasisChange}[2]{[#2\!\leftarrow\!#1]}

A change of basis matrix\index{$\BasisChange{\mathcal A}{\mathcal B}$}.
```

In texlive-2019, this would produce an entry in my `.ind` file of

```
  \item {$[\mathcal  B\tmspace  -\thinmuskip {.1667em}\leftarrow \tmspace  -\thinmuskip {.1667em}\mathcal  A]$}, 
        161
```

whereas in texlive-2020, it produces

```
  \item $[\mathcal  B\
    \subitem \leftarrow \
      \subsubitem \mathcal  A]$, 161
```

It seems that the `\!` is being interpreted as the start of a subitem.

Is there a way I can get the old behaviour back or "protect" my math command so `\!` isn't misinterpreted?

Comment: Clearly it shouldn't behave that way, but my comment is about something else.  When using a math expression as an index term, you really should consider providing a sort field.  The index sort is really dumb -- with `makeindex`, plain ascii -- so you want some control over where this entry gets placed.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that the macro gets expanded when its contents are written to the `.idx` file you get an entry of

```
\indexentry{$\mathcal B\!\leftarrow\!\mathcal A$}
```

(There are other issues with how you've defined things. Try doing `\BasisChange{A}{\mathcal B}` for example.)

<del>The exclamation marks get interpretted as being subitems. I think that just doing the basics of changing your index command to</del>

<del>`\index{B-A@\BasisChange{A}{B}}`</del>

<del>will fix the problem as makeindex shouldn't be parsing for subentries past the `@` if I remember correctly.</del>

**Edit**: Digging a bit deeper this won't work. You could try

```
\index{B-A@{A}{B}|BasisChange}
```

but I've not checked that. **End edit**

Putting `\protect` before `\BasisChange` should also work and if you have a lot of these in your document, you could use `\DeclareRobustCommand` (actually, probably `\DeclareRobustCommand*` would be even better) in place of `\newcommand` so you get the `\protect`ion automatically.

As for why this is broke with the update, I did a cursory search through the git history and it looks like it might be connected with changes regarding robustness that were part of the 2019 patches to LaTeX, but I didn't see anything obvious.